# Identification of plant with quick growing oval leaves, red flowers and pea-like seedlings

Tags: identification

Here's a photo:

[image]

I once had a few seedlings of this plant randomly start growing on my pot, and these are a few features I observed.

It has elliptical leaf shapes with red flowers. I live in the tropics so it might be a tropical plant. I suspect it might have spread its seeds by wind dispersion as some of its seedlings grew in my pots, and all at once.

When it sprouts, it encases its first leaves in this green shell that looks like a giant pea. It grows extremely quickly (approx one new branch every 2 weeks) and has thin branches. Its leaves are light green as grow and darken as they mature.

Also: it guzzles up a lot of water.

Could any kind soul help me identify this plant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is *Caesalpinia pulcherrima*, see here on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesalpinia_pulcherrima). It is also called Mexican bird of paradise or peacock flower. It is indeed a member of the pea family.

Comment: Yup, thank you! I looked up its seedlings and it is indeed very similar to what I had.

Comment: When I have seen it in US garden shops , they use the name " pride of Barbados".

Comment: It seems to have many names (as seen in Wikipedia article). Must be a special plant if it carries so many names!